# How do I append to C++ string without using append function?

Tags: c++, string

I need to append the value of string2 to string1 without using append method in string library.
So far, I've only managed to do this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s1="Messi ";
    string s2="best";
    int i=s1.size();
    int j=s2.size();
    int count;
    for(count=0;count<=j;count++){
        s1[i++]=s2[count];

    }   
    cout<<s1;
}
```

But this, only gives me the value of s1 which is "Messi ". However, I checked by doing this: s1[8]. Since, s1 has index 5, s1[8] shouldn't work, right? But, it does and I get "s" which is in s2. So, it means that the value of s2 is indeed going in s1 but somehow, typing s1 only shows "Messi".

The reason I ask this because we were given this set of instructions to implement the program(yes it appears to be used on c strings but we were told to implement on string object):

```
Step 1: Initialize i= strlen(s1)
Step 2: Initialize j=strlen(s2)
Step 3: Initialize count=0
Step 4: Repeat steps 5 to 7 while count<=j
Step 5: s1[i]=s2[count]
Step 6: i=i+1
Step 7: count=count+1
```

Comment: I assume push_back is also out: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/)

Comment: Is `+=` also out?

Comment: Would `resize` work? Ex: `s1.resize(i+j);` then do the loop.

Comment: What about allocating a new string of the size of both and combining them?

Comment: actually, my instructor gave this task, so he explicitly stated don't use library append function. I suppose += is also out because he advised us to code it like this(in a loop and take the size of both strings like that etc)

Comment: @Rosme you mean I declare s3 and give it the size of s1 and s2 combined? How do I do that? And how, then will I combine what's in s1 and s2?

Comment: *suppose += is also out because he advised us to code it like this(in a loop and take the size of both strings like that etc* -- I guess your professor is into unsafe programming practices.  All of that work on the programmer is just an invitation for bugs to happen.

Comment: @ohnope Your code causes an `assert()` dialog to appear when you run this under Visual Studio with the message `"string subscript out of range"`.  So none of your observations would be observed.

Comment: Since `std::string` is a class, you cannot perform any operations on it without using the class member functions / operator overloads (and therefore the library)  you need to be explicit about what subset you are allowed to use.  Fore example in your attempt you have used the _library function `std::string::operator[]()`.  From your comment it appears that you have been given more information than you have given in the question - you should place all relevant information in the question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh ok.. I used it in DevC++ and it was giving that output there

Comment: @ohnope -- There is a reason for the `assert` to occur.  The answers given about going out-of-bounds is the reason.  The debug version of Visual C++ has these checks.

Comment: The edit makes your question totally different. You are not supposed to use `std::string`  - you are supposed to use `char[]` (C strings).

Comment: you're right. strlen is used on cstrings. But, he told us to implement this on string object

Comment: I think he has misspoken, clearly the answer requires the use of C strings, and that is the only plausible implementation.  I'd go with what is written rather then what may have said verbally.

Comment: actually, he explicitly said it to be used on string objects. That's why. But, yeah I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Why on earth he wants you to  use a bad algorithm made for C string on `std::string`'s is beyond me.

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping out guys. And, may I know the reason for downvotes so I can word it properly?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo well, that's just how the institutes are here in pakistan

Comment: Downvotes possibly because you have asked one question, then posted an image of an entirely different assignment.

Comment: Put the complete algorithm in the question. At least we may then tell you if it's even possible to implement it with `std::string`s. It looks painful.

Comment: I did this because people kept asking me why I was doing this so I had to show that this was a task. Should I remove the pic?

Comment: Plain text is always preferable to pictures so if you can manage to transcribe the complete algorithm that you are supposed to implement as text it'd be a better question

Comment: ok I've edited it

Comment: I think people downvoted because the question is very unclear. You said that a subset of operations is allowed and another subset is not allowed. `std::string::append` is not allowed. `std::string::operator[]` and `std::string::size` are allowed. `std::string::operator+=` could be allowed but you are not sure. What is with `std::string::operator+`? Is it allowed? Step 5 of the given algorithm causes undefined behavior without resizing `s1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s1="string1 ";
    string s2="string2";
    int i=s1.size();
    int j=s2.size();
    s1.resize(i+j);

    for(int count=0;count<=j;count++){

        s1[count+i]=s2[count];

    }   
    cout<<s1;
}
```

After the modifications you've made, I think the code you are looking for is as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char s1[10]="str1 ";
    char s2[]="str2";
    int i=strlen(s1);
    int j=strlen(s2);
    int count = 0;
    for(;count<=j;){
        s1[i]=s2[count];
        i=i+1;
        count=count+1;

    }   
    cout<<s1;
}
```

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @anonymous it only prints the value of s1,it doesn't print concatenated value.

Comment: @ohnope I tested it. it prints `str1 str2`. what is the code you tried exactly?

Comment: @anonymous yeah sorry, it does. I was printing in the loop. Anyway, thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` it's not meant to be used that way.  Class allocates its storage sand operator[] cannot expand it, so string cannot become longer. Documented and guaranteed way to append s2 to s1 is

```
s1 += s2;
```

Then you shouldn't use `std::string` because doing that with it is undefined behavior.. Actually, provided length of those initial values, `std::string` allowed not to use dynamic memory and use class's storage and you have no way to know if it's so from user level of access. It's implementation details.

You have to `resize()` string before writing in it and hold on idea that `size()` of string as an index unlike length includes zero character. Resize can change type of storage and allocate storage needed to hold second string. `max_size()` returns actual  amount characters  string can store without reallocation.

Comment: oh. But, as I said when I wrote s1[8], it did give me 's' which was in s2. So, it means that the value is going there and space is being allocated, right?

Comment: @ohnope Doing that would be undefined behaviour. Space is not being allocated. Chances are that your two string objects are placed next to eachother in memory and since they contain short strings, they may be short-string-optimized and you read from the memory of the second string. Still UB.

Comment: *So, it means that the value is going there and space is being allocated, right?* -- Wrong.  Undefined behavior can do strange things.  As a matter of fact, your code `assert()`'s when run using Visual C++ as soon as you access those out-of-bounds elements.

Comment: @ohnope zero character of first string. size() includes it. SO printing string doesn't work.

Comment: oh ok.. So, you're saying that I shouldn't use this approach and use += or append function?

Comment: @ohnope or `resize()` s1 first, and for loop's body should be  `s1[count+i]=s2[count];`  you have to copy every character. actually while() loop looks neater for this purpose. or range-based loop.

Comment: @ohnope Yes `+=` would be the most obvious. Your approach in the question is not even an option since it causes Undefined Behaviour (anything can happen - anything).

Comment: oh okay. Thanks for helping, guys.

Comment: @ohnope at very least, make use of such site as https://en.cppreference.com and links it references

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `+=` operator or just use `insert`:

```
string s1 = "Messi ";
string s2 = "best";

s1.insert(s1.size(), s2);
cout << s1 << endl;
cout << s1[8] << endl; // s
```

Or with iterators:

```
s1.insert(s1.cend(), s2.cbegin(), s2.cend());
```